# Clickable classname and line number in console using log4j

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, log4j

The `log4j.properties` below displays the location of the logging event using `%l`. The output is a bit too long with the fully qualified classname and method name.

```
# root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, file

# redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p: %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %l] %m%n

# redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${catalina.home}/logs/mylog.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p: %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %l] %m%n
```

**Actual Output:**

[image]

```
[INFO: 2015-08-30 14:24:07 com.mypackage.MyAction.execute(MyAction.java:64)] This is an INFO message.
```

What is the correct `ConversionPattern` in the properties file so it only takes the clickable portion of the location?

**Intended Output:**

```
[INFO: 2015-08-30 14:24:07 MyAction.java:64] This is an INFO message.
```

**Where:**

`MyAction.java:64` is clickable in the console.

Comment: Nothing is clickable in a command prompt window, where `System.out` prints it.

Comment: If you're referring to the Eclipse "Console" view, then nothing is clickable, i.e. a link. Answer: *There is no correct pattern*

Comment: @Andreas: in Eclipse it is possible to create a clickable link. See my answer below.

Comment: @Burkhard Thank you, I stand corrected. I tried it before commenting but didn't know the trick was to surround with parenthesis. You got my up-vote. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean the Console output in Eclipse, you can get a klickable link.

An appender like this should work:

```
<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %m (%F:%L) in %t%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

It works, because the Eclipse Console parses the pattern (FileName.java:lineNumber) to be a link to FileName.java at line lineNumber.

An easy test (creates a link to line that jumps to line 6) is:

```
public class TestLink
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("(" + new TestLink().getClass().getSimpleName()
            + ".java:" + 6 + ")");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, regarding the appender, it appears to be xml. Can you tell me where to find the xml to put the appender settings you gave?

Comment: @silver: take a look at this link: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html (i haven't used log4j in a while, if you have problems with the configuration, just ask.)

Answer (score 3):

You should look at [`PatternLayout` javadoc](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html) to see what are all the possible patterns.

Log message like the following:

```
[INFO: 2015-08-30 14:24:07 MyAction.java:64] This is an INFO message.
```

can be obtained with:

```
[%p: %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %F:%L] %m%n
```

Comment: That still doesn't make the output "clickable", not that I think *any* format string can.

Comment: @Andreas I don't think the OP wants to make the output "clickable". I think what the OP meant by "clickable portion" was the class name (with Eclipse, only the class name is indeed "clickable")

Comment: If OP is talking about the Eclipse console view, then nothing is clickable, i.e. a link. Question is meaningless (or answer is "you can't").

Comment: I have added a screenshot under Actual Output as reference. The part that says `SortMemberAction.java:64` is clickable in the Eclipse console (light blue) and when clicked, it jumps to that line. I would like to obtain that portion only displayed as a link and not as text.

Comment: This is an old post of mine and I didn't realize I wasn't able to mark an accepted answer. Tunaki would have also been correct if the pattern was `(%F:%L)` based on Burkhard's solution. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it using `log4j.properties` file based on accepted answer:

```
# direct log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p: %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} (%F:%L)] %m%n
```